# iOS: Very Simple Segue Not Working

Tags: ios, xcode, segue

Starting with an empty project here...

If I make a `UITableViewController` and make a segue from a prototype cell to some other `UIViewController` using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Click</kbd> method, nothing happens. It is of the modal variety.

If I use the same method to segue from a navigation bar button it works just fine, but when I run the iOS simulator I can't even select the table cell. It's just completely unresponsive.

I was under the impression that I don't need to write any code for a simple segue such as this to work, is this false?

Edit: Fixed the issue. For those as new as I, remember to make sure "selection" is enabled in the TableView, AND TableCell Attributes windows.

Comment: Do you actually use the prototype cells? If you register cells with the same identifier in code these will take precedence. If you use a different reuseIdentifier and use something like `if cell == nil { // create cell }` the prototype cell from storyboard won't be used either. So verify that you display the correct cell. Change it's backgroundColor in the storyboard or something.

Comment: Literally, I'm starting from an empty project just to test this behavior, and it is persisting. I start a blank project, grab a table view controller, set it to the initial view, grab another view controller and try to make a segue from a prototype cell to the latter controller. It still happens if I use a static cell too.

Comment: You do need to populate the cells, otherwise there are none to select. The fact that you see separator lines in your table view, doesn't mean there are any cells there.

Comment: Ok so I populated the cells and it works when they are static, however this was really just testing that I have basic knowledge. The real issue is that my cells are dynamic, and I have populated them with 2 test pieces of data. Do I need to write code to put in a segue in this scenario or can I just use the storyboard method?

Comment: You can create the segue in the storyboard like you said you did. Is that not working now that you've populated the cells?

Answer (score 0):

On the Storyboard, Right click on the prototype cell and Under "`Triggered Segues`", from "`selection`" make your segue to desired Viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was a combination of:

- making sure I was subclassing UITableViewCell,
- making sure the Segue had an identifier assigned to it in the Attributes Inspector, and
- I was setting a reuse identifier for my subclassed UITableViewCell in the Storyboard's Attributes Inspector (NOT programmatically).

Answer (score -1):

Did you set your cell to static?
[image]

Also have a look in this [amazing tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/81880/storyboards-tutorial-swift-part-2) in how to archive what you are looking for.